# Report should get populate based on search fields in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have report which consists of two search fields and two drop down lists.

my question is here if i search for value in search field matched results should populate in drop down and based on these values only other search field and drop down should work. the data should get populate from single sql table.

i am new please let me know to change format.w

Comment: If yuou check what properties are available for each parameter, you'll see that you can specify a source in the `Available Values` page. This is also covered in the documentation

Comment: I have one search parameter which will have like condition search in DB for values what is searched for in search parameter and another also same working fine but thing i need to connect those two search parameters

Comment: The query you specify for the second parameter can use the first parameter. It's all in the docs